# IS there a possibility to get the link of a PDF generated from a google Doc template that is created using google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to generate a personalized letter to some clients, using all the data from a sheet, I have generated the doc and the pdf, but I can't get the URL from the PDF archive.

The problem is when I use the code that generated me the url to the doc archive, doesn't work giving me the PDF URL.

The code I'm using is this, I changed some things from a youtube tutorial

```
function createNewGoogleDocs() {
    //This value should be the id of your document template that we created in the last step
    const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('***');
  
   //This value should be the id of the folder where you want your completed documents stored
   const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('+++')
   //Here we store the sheet as a variable
   const sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('Friends')
  
   //Now we get all of the values as a 2D array
   const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
      //Start processing each spreadsheet row
      rows.forEach(function(row, index){
     //Here we check if this row is the headers, if so we skip it
   if (index === 0) return;
    //Here we check if a document has already been generated by looking at 'Document Link', if so we skip it
    if (row[6]) return;

    //Using the row data in a template literal, we make a copy of our template document in our destinationFolder
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[1]}, ${row[0]} template_letter` , tempFolder)

    //Once we have the copy, we then open it using the DocumentApp
    const temp = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())

    //All of the content lives in the body, so we get that for editing
    const body = temp.getBody();

    
    //In these lines, we replace our replacement tokens with values from our spreadsheet row
    body.replaceText('{{Name}}', row[0]);
    body.replaceText('{{Email}}', row[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{Favorite_product}}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{{Date}}', row[3]);
    body.replaceText('{{SuscriptionDate}}', row[4]);
    body.replaceText('{{User}}', row[5]);

    
    //We make our changes permanent by saving and closing the document
    temp.saveAndClose();

    //Folder with PDF archives
    const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('///') 

    const pdfletter = temp.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
    pdfFolder.createFile(pdfletter)

   ** Here is where i can´t get the URL, the message says that pdfletter is not a function

    //Store the url of our new document in a variable
    const url = pdfletter.getUrl();
    
    //Write that value back to the 'Document Link' column in the spreadsheet. 
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 7).setValue(url)**
  })
}
```

Comment: About `IS there a possibility to get the link of a PDF generated from a google Doc template that is created using google sheets?`, I think that in your script, the URL is `const url = pdfletter.getUrl();`. How about this?

Answer (score 0):

Your script is very similar to the one referenced in [How do I fix the output location of my PDF? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74802941/1330560).

**Replace:**

```
    const pdfletter = temp.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
    pdfFolder.createFile(pdfletter)
```

---

**With**

```
var pdfletter= temp.getBlob();
pdfletter.setName(temp.getName() + ".pdf");
pdfFolder.createFile(pdfletter);
```